# Nexus 5 doesn't show in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows-8.1, nexus-5

I have some problems to connect nexus 5 with eclipse.
I am using windows 8.1 and I have installed the nexus drivers from google_usb->http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

I can see my device in ADB(using adb -devices) and in DDMS on eclipse, but I can't send apps to debbug it, just nexus doesn't appear in target in eclipse.
In Device Manager my nexus appear like Android Composite ADB Device

I have the developer options enabled and USB debugging too.

http://www.htcmania.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=607751&stc=1&d=1414926573

EDIT:

I only just tested with android studio and it works, but I don't understand why in eclipse doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it says connected as a media device. If it says connected as a camera, tap to change the USB options and check the "connect as a media device" check box.

Comment: No, I am "connected as a media device(MTP)", but thanks